# SetFocus to Control From Code Behind with JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, code-behind

I am trying to set focus to a page control (Textbox) by using the registerStartupScript method. However, I have been unsuccessful. Here is what I have tried:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SetFocus", "<script>document.getElementById('" + this.tbAdjust.ClientID + "').focus();</script>");
```

And:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "focus", "<script>$('" + this.tbAdjust.ClientID + "');</script>");
```

Can't seem to get it. Seems like a pretty straight forward question, if you all need anymore code, let me know. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you inspect the generated javascript to see if it works?

Comment: Yeah and it looked fine. I found the problem, I was calling this in the wrong button click...Its Monday for sure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally `tbAdjust.Focus();` at code behind should work. Here are the scripts.

### Without Ajax

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "focus", 
"document.getElementById('" + this.tbAdjust.ClientID + "').focus();", true);
```

### With Ajax

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "focus", 
"document.getElementById('" + this.tbAdjust.ClientID + "').focus();", true);
```

If you want to use jQuery, you need # at the front.

For example,  `"$('#" + this.tbAdjust.ClientID + "').focus();"`

Comment: I tried the method w/ out Ajax, (Which is what i pretty much had in my example code, and its still not working.

Comment: I got it. I actually was calling it in the wrong spot...It is working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't jQuery's .ready() method work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#target').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock instead:

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("SetFocus", "<script>document.getElementById('" + this.tbAdjust.ClientID + "').focus();</script>");
```

Comment: Page is depreciated. VS says to use ClientScript.